# Word 2007 multiple BeforeClose event handling

Tags: event-handling, add-in, office-2007, word-2007

I have office 2007 installed on the windows 7 platform.
In the Word application exists our supplier's add-in that catches BeforeClose document event and asks customer the question before exitting.
Now, I developed MY custom add-in that also catches BeforeClose document event and performs some operation.
**The question is**: HOW can I control, which of the "catching" will perform FIRST and which SECOND?
I need that MY add-in will work first and the supplier code will work after me, before the documnet will closed.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Milo

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see would be the loading order of the addins. You might need to "name" your addin file so it loads first (not sure there is another way), then check if it effectively triggers first on all you system configurations.